# How to capture strings using dotNET regex when source string begins with a specific substring

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following string:

> city-Rio de Janeiro+Belo Horizonte+Santos

and I could use this regex successfully to extract city names:

```
(?<=city\-|\+)(?<city>[a-zA-Z\s+\-]+)(?=\+|$)
```

but actually the regex above is treating the substring "city-" as optional, how can I make sure the string starts with "city-" and capture all subsequent strings separated by plus sign?

Answer (score 0):

You could first try and substitute `^city-` with nothing in your input: if the resulting string is the same, not what you want.

If, on the opposite, the substitution succeeds, just split the transformed string with `+`, groups will be city names. Job done!

Alternative for step 1: look for first index of substring "city-", it should be zero. Not even the need for a regex.